# Missing templates after re-installing VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-templates

I installed VS 2008 and I installed .NET 3.5 SP1 and I got all templates.

Then, I had to uninstall VS 2008 (please don't ask why) without uninstalling .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 or anything else.

After that, I re-installed VS 2008 back, then I open up VS 2008 and found that when I add a new item the Entity Framework template is not among the list anymore.

Could someone please help on how to resolve this problem?

Thank you so much!

Ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you reinstall VS2008 without VS2008 SP1? I believe EF templates were an SP1 feature.

Comment: You are absolutely right!  I forgot to re-install back VS2008SP1.  Confused that with .NET3.5SP1.  Thanks!